# How to get public key from private key in C?

Tags: addresses, private-key

I know the theory behind generating the public address.

1. convert to 65 byte uncompressed key
2. removed first "04" byte, we have
   5f37d20e5b18909361e0ead7ed17c69b417bee70746c9e9c2bcb1394d921d4ae612d83e3487012034792ff36357ee25f382913cfeb54a8622b7ef35d635d8740 for 0x025f37d20e5b18909361e0ead7ed17c69b417bee70746c9e9c2bcb1394d921d4ae
3. Keccak this 64 bytes to 32 bytes:
   81862025a6a8b333133c9b9ad09d3103ccabfb769edc3e9b01500ca7241d470a
4. Get last 20 bytes: 0xd09D3103CcABfb769eDc3e9B01500Ca7241D470A

I'm interested if there is a library or code written in C that already does that?

Comment: In worst case, I'll reverse engineer Nethereum signer class https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/3287e072d57561ce1ab8b9649320a486fa1683ee/src/Nethereum.Signer/EthECKey.cs